# Nhibernate cfg xml can't connect to Postgres

Tags: .net, nhibernate, postgresql

Test exception is :

Test method DevLair.Tests.GenerateSchema_Fixture.Can_generate_schema> threw exception: 
 NHibernate.HibernateException:

key=value argument incorrect in ConnectionString

Parameter Name : initial catalog ---> System.ArgumentException: key=valuergument incorrect in ConnectionString

hibernate.cfg.xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<hibernate-configuration  xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2" >
    <session-factory name="NHibernate.Test">
        <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.NpgsqlDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.connection_string">
            Server=postgres48.1gb.ru;initial catalog=xgb_dlusers;User ID=xgb_dlusers;Password=****;
        </property>
        <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

what's wrong with initial catalog ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the looks of the error, the connection string is invalid.

Heres an example Npgsqldriver connection string:

```
Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Possible problems with yours:

- use `Database` instead of `initial catalogue` (this is most likely the problem)
- use `User Id` instead of U`ser ID` (don't know if it's case sensitive)
- Missing port

Comment: It works ! Thank you. Nhibirnate tutorials is really crappy :(

Comment: You're both more than welcome to submit your patch for the tutorials/docs.

Comment: Sorry, Diego - didn't mean to sound ungrateful :)